# WCF service returning HTML instead of response

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I created a WCF service which connects some websites. But when I try to consume it, I get this error. What can cause it? Funny thing is, I duplicated WCF service from another working one so I'm confused.

The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Runtime Error</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
...
```

Comment: Have you seen http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3b3cd305-3158-4594-a162-6ff62ee6ac4b/the-content-type-texthtmlcharsetutf8-of-the-response-message-does-not-match-the-content-type-of ?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I always try is to right click on the service reference in the client project and select update. Sometimes this happens when the local reference is out of date.

Answer (score 0):

I found out I forgot to change class on asmx file, it didn't match cs file. It worked when I set it true.